# composer windows vs ubuntu

Tags: xampp, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

Good evening,

This question is has to do with the PHP composer packet management.  I have installed in on our test environment (xampp) without any issues and have downloaded the necessary package without any problems (package name: mpdf).  After I issue the command to get the package, the vendor package showed up as it should have and my project worked great.

Fast forward, we are not ready to deploy this whole application to a linux(ubuntu 16.04) box using a versioning system (svn) and all the files that were on the test system have been deployed to production.  The only problem is that the specific parts of our site on production that needs the mpdf package does not work.

My question is this, even though the vendor folder was also copies to production using SVN, is there anything else for us to do to make this work on the production box?

I am mainly speaking about any necessary steps that might need to performed on the ubuntu box?

Thank for all the help in advance,
George Eivaz

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.  It had to do with the permissions not being correct on Ubuntu.